# SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed When setting default value in boolean column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord

Im trying to set the default value of a boolean column in my SQLite3 database, this is my migration:

```
class AddDefaultFalseToHasErrorsBooleanColumns < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    change_column_null :batch_rows, :has_errors, false
    change_column_null :contacts_files, :has_errors, false
  end
end
```

When I run the migration I get these kind of errors:

```
SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: contacts_files.has_errors
```

Is there something wrong with the migration?

Comment: If you already have rows then maybe you need to update the NULL rows first? e.g. `BatchRow.where(has_errors: nil).update_all(has_errors: false)` then place your `change_column_null` call. Repeat process for `ContractFile`

Comment: Awesome! that was the issue, please add it as an answer and I will accept it, thank you!

Comment: You're not actually setting a default here - you need to call `change_column_null(:batch_rows, :has_errors, false, false)` as the signature is `change_column_null(table_name, column_name, null, default = nil)`. Maybe some day in the future we will have methods with keyword args that actually make sense. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-change_column_null